# node.js Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.assign'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, lodash

I have installed node.js in windows 64bit and i run into this when runnig gulp on local project.

another note: npm install went good with packages.json

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.assign'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NBCredit_FRTE\RelyToolsSln\RelyTools.Web\node_modules\gulp-jshint\node_modules\lodash.clone\node_modules\lodash._baseclone\index.js:9:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
     PS D:\NBCredit_FRTE\RelyToolsSln\RelyTools.Web>
```

this is my package.json (i'm trying to setup this project: https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa)

```
{
  "name": "webapi-angularjs-spa",
  "description": "SPA Demo app with AngularJS",
  "author": "Shiju Varghese",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "repository": "https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-util": "~2.2.14",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "~0.2.1",
    "jshint": "~2.4.3",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.4.2",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-size": "~0.1.3",
    "gulp-rimraf": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-open": "~0.2.8",
    "gulp-connect": "~2.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

this is my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    jshintreporter = require('jshint-stylish'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    size = require('gulp-size'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    open = require('gulp-open'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

var filePath = {
    appjsminify: { src: './Scripts/app/**/*.js', dest: './Scripts/app' },
    libsjsminify: { src: ['./Scripts/libs/**/*.js', '!*.min.js', '!/**/*.min.js'], dest: './Scripts/libs/' },
    jshint: { src: './Scripts/app/**/*.js' },
    minifycss: { src: ['./Content/themes/**/*.css', '!*.min.css', '!/**/*.min.css'], dest: './Content/themes/' }
};



gulp.task('app-js-minify', function () {
    gulp.src(filePath.appjsminify.src)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('ngscripts.js'))
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath.appjsminify.dest));
});

gulp.task('libs-js-minify', function () {
    /*Excludes already minified files.*/
    gulp.src(filePath.libsjsminify.src)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath.libsjsminify.dest));
});


gulp.task('jshint', function () {
    gulp.src(filePath.jshint.src)
      .pipe(jshint())
      .pipe(jshint.reporter(jshintreporter));
});


gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    /*Excludes already minified files.*/
    gulp.src(filePath.minifycss.src)
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath.minifycss.dest));
}); 

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    gulp.src(
        [
            'Scripts/app/ngscripts.js',
            'Scripts/libs/angular-ui/select2.min.js',
            'Scripts/libs/select2/select2.min.js',
            'Scripts/libs/semantic/semantic.min.js',
            'Scripts/libs/**/*.min.js',
            'Scripts/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
            '!Scripts/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js',
            './Content/themes/semantic/semantic.min.css',
            './Content/themes/Site.min.css',
            './Content/themes/select2/select2.min.css'
        ], { read: false })
    .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
});
gulp.task('build', ['app-js-minify', 'libs-js-minify', 'minify-css']);
gulp.task('cleanbuild', ['clean']);

gulp.task('tests', function () {
    connect.server({ 
        port:8000
    });
    var testUrl = "http://localhost:8000/SpecRunner.html";
    gulp.src("./SpecRunner.html")
      .pipe(open("", { url: testUrl }));
});

//gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', ['js']);
```

Comment: Well, do you have `lodash.assign` installed?  Try `npm i lodash.assign`.  Did you run `npm i` at all before trying to do stuff with your project?  You're probably missing dependencies.

Comment: Please supply a relevant, minimal copy of your gulpfile that demonstrates the problem. There's not enough information to help you right now.

Comment: Try to update your npm and node.

Comment: I run `npm i lodash.assign` and run `npm i` and get the same error. I've edit the post to put more information regarding on this project.

Comment: npm version: 2.14.12

Comment: Now every time i run `npm i lodash.[NAMEMODULE]`, it install the NAMEMODULE, but then when i run `gulp` again, it throws another NAMEMODULE, for example now it shows: **Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._getarray'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)**. could i have some way to have all modules of lodash installed?

Comment: Where do you declare `gulp-minify-css` as dependency? You require it but its not in your package.json.

Comment: Correct, when i run ´npm install´, node sugest another modules, so i've changed to that modules in the packages. And forgot to look correctly to gulp file. To manage this issue i had to remove all node_modules, set all dependencies correctly and then install. thank you all for your help. how can i close this post or mark as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. `npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-jshint`
2. `npm uninstall --save lodash`
3. `npm cache clean`
4. `npm install --save-dev gulp-jshint`

Not sure that is the problem in your case, but sometimes the node cache get messed up and messages like that appear. basically, lodash should be installed as a dependency for `gulp-jshint` when that package is being installed. you should need to install it manually unless you're calling some of lodash's methods directly.

Cleaning the node cache after uninstalling, should download and install the package from scratch, fixing any dependency errors.